# filter online user in REDIS with pagination

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, redis

I'm developing a website where I'm using REDIS to store the list of user. It's in a sorted set where the score is simply the time when they were put into the list. Paginating through this list is very easy. The problematic part comes, when I want to show from this list only the online users with paginations if necessary. I have for every minute a SET where I store only userIDs, the ones whom was online.

The problem, I can't intersect SET with SORTED SET. So what I was thinking, is to transform the online users set to a sorted set without score and use INTERSECT at the time of the request, if someone come online in the same minute, thats not a problem, they will be shown in the next minute, and I simply use a ZINTERSTORY command.

Does someone have a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news - you can actually use the ZINTERSTORE command on sorted **and** regular sets, e.g.:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> sadd s a b c
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> smembers s
1) "b"
2) "c"
3) "a"
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd z 0 a 1 b 3 d
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange z 0 -1
1) "a"
2) "b"
3) "d"
127.0.0.1:6379> zinterstore t 2 s z
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange t 0 -1
1) "a"
2) "b"
127.0.0.1:6379> zinterstore tt 1 s
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange tt 0 -1 withscores
1) "a"
2) "1"
3) "b"
4) "1"
5) "c"
6) "1"
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I just read it works only with sorted sets, didn't try it myself if it works with normal sets. But then here if I'm right, the weight is 1 for every element in the normal SET, right?